# Access two values in format() formula

Tags: python, string, format, spyder, chatbot

I am developing some code and I want to access to two vaules when you use the format() formula. When I use this formula in Spyder:

```
response, play =  "My name is {0}".format("John")
```

I get this Error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I want to know it there is way to obtain the two values. I am expecting when I use the formula to get the next value

```
response = "My name is {0}"
play = "John"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
play = "John"
response = f"My name is {play}"
```

Or if you want to assign them in one-line, you could try this:

```
play,response = "John","My name is {0}".format(play)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, if you want that result you would just use

```
response, play = "My name is {0}", "John"
```

Since you're assigning to 2 variables on the left, you need 2 equivalent values on the right, but you only offer one. Your code of `"My name is {0}".format("John")` translates to `'My name is John'` which is a single string value. Python doesn't know which of the two variables on the left it should assign this to, or what to do with the other one. Hence it was expecting too many values (2) for the number you provide (1).

If you actually meant that you wanted:

```
response = "My name is John"
play = "John"
```

then you would use:

```
response, play = "My name is {0}".format("John"), "John"
```

Assuming you had "John" in a variable:

```
name = "John"
response, play = "My name is {0}".format(name), name
```

If you're using Python 3.6+, f-strings are cooler:

```
response, play = f"My name is {name}", name
```

Either way, the point is if you're assigning to n variables on the left, you need n separate values on the right.

Answer (score 0):

If MrNobody33 has not answered your question you may consider reviewing tuple unpacking or assigning multiple variables.

```
response, play = "My name is {0}".format("John"), "Other name is {0}".format("Brett")
print(response)
print(play)
```